# MoPub #withMediatedNetworkConfiguration explained

Tags: mopub

IMHO the MoPub documentation lacks on code samples explaining the usage of available functions. This function is #withMediatedNetworkConfiguration.

Why is this function important? In the [Network SDK initialization](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/initialize/#network-sdk-initialization) it says

> Note that you can call **.withMediatedNetworkConfiguration()** on your SdkConfiguration.Builder to pass network configurations required for pre-initialization. Otherwise expect your first attempt to pre-initialize mediated networks to fail because no network data is cached at this point. All your subsequent attempts to pre-initialize should succeed for the duration of the app’s life.

Meaning if you call the app first time, only MoPub's Marketplace will be initialized. Mediation networks did not get required parameters during init and will fail. Next launch everything will work.

So MoPub does give you a chance to call #withMediatedNetworkConfiguration to pass required parameters even on first launch.

But how is all this accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this lacks of documentation.

Facebook for example does not need any parameters mediated by MoPub, it will successfully init on first app launch. AdColony and Vungle (and most of the others) will **NOT** init on first launch. This is loss in revenue due to lack of competition.

Let's take a look at AdColony, which gave me some headache. Simple MoPubSDK init with AdColony init looks like this.

```
SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("362da1882dfc49f3a33b92ea1708f3a5")
            .withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(AdColonyAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), adColonySettings)
            .build();

MoPub.initializeSdk(activity, sdkConfiguration, listener);
```

Alright. But how does the AdColonyAdapterConfiguration#initializeNetwork look like. This gives us some ideas has is the content of the passed configuration is.

[image]

Not to hard. Two strings are passed (appId and zoneId) and one string array (allZoneIds).

Reading the MoPub documentation up and down helped me find the [AdColony mediation guide](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/mediation/networks/adcolony/#set-up-adcolony-on-the-mopub-dashboard) saying
[image]

For my understanding appId and zoneId is required and allZoneIds is kind off optional?! But which zoneId if multiple are used in my app? To make things short. This is all wrong. In 
AdColonyAdapterConfiguration#initializeNetwork we can find out that only appId and allZoneIds is really needed.

See here
[image]

AllZoneIds is a retrieved by Json.jsonArrayToStringArray. But how is that formatted again?! Let's come to an end.

**Lets look at the comprehensive answer how to initialize adColony with MoPub *on first launch*:**

```
Map<String, String> adColonySettings = new HashMap<>();
    adColonySettings.put("appId", "yourAppId");
    adColonySettings.put("zoneId", "ANYOfYourZoneIds");
    adColonySettings.put("allZoneIds", "[\"bannerZoneId, interstitialZoneId\"]");

    SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("moPubId")
 .withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(AdColonyAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), adColonySettings)
            .build();

    MoPub.initializeSdk(activity, sdkConfiguration, initSdkListener());
```

Another sample is Vungle. Init it like this:

```
Map<String, String> vungleSettings = new HashMap<>();
    vungleSettings.put("appId", "vungleAppId");

    SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("moPubId")
            .withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(VungleAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), vungleSettings)
            .build();
```